# OCaml Syntax Environment and Syntax Error

Tags: syntax, syntax-error, ocaml

```
let x = 132;;
let f x = 
    let x = 15 in (fun x -> print_int x) 150;;
f 2;;
```

The output is 150.

My question is: why "print_int" does not perform yet? is that because `fun x-> print_int x` just defines a function, but not required to perform yet? Does the inside function just simply print 15?

I wanted to respond to my guess, and when I modify the code to this:

```
# let x = 132;;
val x : int = 132
# let f x = 
  let x = 15 in (let g x = print_int x) 150;;
Error: Syntax error
```

an error is prompted. Why? 
(I was just trying to name the function "g", but syntax error?)

Anyone can help? thx

Answer (score 3):

To solve the syntax error you'd have to write it like this (you were missing the `in` keyword and the function's name):

```
let f x =
let x = 15 in let g x = print_int x in g 150;;
```

To understand why look at the type of your first example in the toplevel:

```
# (fun x -> print_int x);; (* define a function *)
- : int -> unit = <fun>
# (fun x -> print_int x) 150;; (* define a function and call it with 150 *)
150- : unit = ()
# (let g x = print_int x);; (* define a value named 'g' that is a function , 'g' has the type below *)
val g : int -> unit = <fun>
# (let g x = print_int x) 150;; (* you can't do this, the code in the paranthesis is not a value: it is a let-binding or a definition of a value *)
Error: Syntax error
```

The `x` in `f x` and `let x = 15` have nothing to do with the x inside your function, the `x` in the innermost scope takes precedence (this is called shadowing).